# Not making a table in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have tried different ways to solve this problem, but none of them have solved the problem.This part of the code is for building a relationship in Laravel, but this code works in Laravel 5 but is error-prone in Laravel 7.

Error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shoplaravel`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `role_user` add constraint `role_user_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
    });
    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('permissions')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys need to be of the exact same type as the column they're referencing.

Laravel's default user table migration uses `$table->increments('id');` - an alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')`.

Change `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->bigIncrements('id');` in your `roles` and `permissions` table migrations.

More on migration columns: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: I really thank you. you are life saver.My problem was solved. <3

Answer (score 0):

Remove `BigInteger` and use only `unsignedInteger`

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
    });
    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('permission_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('permissions')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

Comment: It's a problem again: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shoplaravel`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `role_user` add constraint `role_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)